# how to change/relocate the cs file path of OpenCover

Tags: c#, opencover

I want to change the cs file path of `result.xml` like the following.
The default file path is the build path, how to change it in the execute time of **OpenCover**?

```
    <Files>
        <File uid="1" fullPath="D:\Demo\TestProject\MathFunctionsTest.cs" />
    </Files>
```

--->

```
    <Files>
        <File uid="1" fullPath="D:\Demo\TestProject\case1\MathFunctionsTest.cs" />
    </Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change it at execute time, the paths that OpenCover displays come from the PDB files. If you want to change them after, but before you use a tool like ReportGenerator, then you could probably use an XSLT file to transform the XML.